# Automated Shopify analytics email

Tags: google-analytics, shopify, email

I'm looking in the possibility to send automated website performance emails to clients from a Shopify or Google Analytics API for their own website I manage. It must include metrics like sales, visitors, conversion rate etc.. basically what's available on the Shopify dashboard.

As a designer with html/css skills only, I am unsure about the scope of what I am asking, could I get this done for a couple of hundred dollars or is this something that requires extensive programming?

Compass delivers a similiar service as i'm looking for, I need that with personal branding.

Answer (score 1):

Go to analytics, then navigate to customization > Dashboards. There you may set up some sophisticated reports and schedule regular emails with 'advansced options' by pressing 'email' button when a dashboard is ready.
Here is the help article https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1068218?hl=en